# Question about されては堪らない

Tags: grammar

I cannot completely grasp the meaning されて堪らない. As far as I can understand ~てたまらない means "Really want to do, extremely.", but I'm a bit of unsere with passive voice in the following sentence.

Some sort of translation:  "I want you to tell me frankly. You are clever so I understand that you are thinking thoroughly, and you absolutely cannot stop being self-sufficent(自己完結) about it."

> 率直なところを述べてほしいね。頭のいい君のことだ、いろいろ考えているのはわかっているけど、それで自己完結されちゃあ堪らない。

Context:
[image]

Comment: `～てたまらない` means "extremely" and has nothing do with wanting, unless the `～て` is `ほしくて`, or `～たくて`.  For example, `眠くてたまらない　→　extremely tired`, `暑くてたまらない　→　very hot`, or `車を買いたくてたまらない　→　really want to buy a car`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the speaker that is doing both the される and the たまらない in this sentence. (i.e. he is the one being passively subjected to the other person doing 自己完結).

In general I don't think you would go too far wrong to remember たまらない literally as "cannot bear" rather than something abstracted like "extremely". Most of its uses follow naturally from that literal definition.

[三省堂 entry for たまらない 【▽堪らない】](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BE%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

> (3)…されることに耐えられない。とても困る。 
>   「毎朝五時に起こされたのでは―ない」

So in this case, the speaker is saying that he really doesn't appreciate being 自己完結'd by the other person, and is hoping (asking) that they stop.

---

Also, be sure you understand what is meant by 自己完結. If you aren't completely clear about the sense of an unfamiliar Japanese word and it doesn't fit super-snugly into the context, consult a Japanese monolingual dictionary, especially for phrases like this when EDICT is more confusing than helpful with its short definitions. Concerning [自己完結](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%87%AA%E5%B7%B1%E5%AE%8C%E7%B5%90):

> 何かの物事について、自分自身の中だけで納得したり決着したりしているさま。「周りの人からするとまだ決着していないのに、独りよがりに決着している」といった意味合いで否定的に用いられることもある。
>   (Regarding some matter, the state of being satisfied or reaching a resolution only within oneself. Sometimes used with a negative nuance of "though no resolution has yet been reached from the perspective of the people around him, he himself selfishly considers it settled".)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Then this translation seems legit: "I want you to tell me frankly. You are clever so I understand that you are thinking thoroughly, but it's prolematic if reach conclusion about it only by yourself on me." ? Well, even though 自己完結 is in passive here, I don't think that the one who is thought about is the speaker, so I tried to add "on me" to show the passive form in translation.